# Построить микросервисную архитектуру с обработкой промежуточных результатов

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, rabbitmq, микросервисы

Задача звучит так:

1. Есть три сервиса: интернет-магазин, склад интернет магазина и АПИ банка
2. Покупатель делает заказ и получает счет для оплаты в банке
3. Во время ожидания ответа от банка об успешной оплате информация о заказе должна где-то храниться как ожидающая оплаты.

Вопрос 1. Как и где лучше хранить информацию о временном заказе?

Вопрос 2. Как правильно забронировать товар на складе?

Задача должна быть решена с использованием микросервисной архитектуры и очередей. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой патерн лучше использовать и как логически должен быть выстроен процесс в общих чертах.

Answer (score 2):

Логически - склад отвечает за товар. Банк - за переводы. И тому и другому нет никакого смысла хранить заказы клиентов. Значит за заказы должен отвечать сервис заказов или что у вас есть ближайшее к сервису заказов.

Чтобы бронировать товар на складе, просто как идея, добавьте бронь заказа отдельной записью в склад. Тогда, чтобы понять, сколько доступно товаров, надо посчитать "Доступно для заказа" = "Всего товаров" - "Забронировано товаров".